# 'Thank you for taking your time writing' or 'Thank you for taking your time to write' ?

Tags: meaning, difference, infinitive-vs-gerund

A person gave me an answer on English.SE and I commented:

> Thank you for taking your time writing this wonderful answer!

Now, looking at the sentence in retrospect, even though I am not a native English speaker (duh, otherwise I wouldn't be asking a question on ELL.SE), I find the sentence a bit odd.

To get my point across, let me rephrase the sentence:

> Thank you for taking your time **to write** this wonderful answer!

With my relatively little knowledge and understanding of English, I feel that using 'writing' (as I did in the original sentence) emphasizes the *very process of writing the answer*, whereas using 'to write' emphasizes the *mere fact* that an answer has been given, and a wonderful one at that.

This is exactly why I feel the original sentence is a little bit awkward and the second, revised one would have been more apt.

**Am I correct or are the quoted sentences virtually synonymous?**

Comment: It's an interesting question because I think that a native would be relatively lax and might just say your version, even though it's not *technically* what is meant. The second is definitely the correct phrasing for what you wanted to say but I have a feeling that you would hear both from natives and they could both be meant to mean the same thing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[taking your time](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+time) means doing something slowly: this is probably not the meaning that you want! The correct expression to use is "taking the time".

The gerund works with **taking your time**:

> You are taking your time writing those letters- get a move on!

But idiomatically the gerund doesn't work with **taking the time**. The idiomatic version is therefore

> Thank you for taking the time to write this wonderful answer!

Here is an [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=taking%20the%20time%20to%20write%2C%20taking%20the%20time%20writing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctaking%20the%20time%20to%20write%3B%2Cc0) that shows that the infinitive form is common but the gerund is never used.

Comment: Thank you pointing out another mistake of mine and please, let me ask you for one more thing: could you elaborate on the case when neither _taking your time_ nor _taking the time_ are used at all? What would the difference between such two sentences be?

Comment: What's wrong with "Thank you for taking the time to write this wonderful answer" - it seems 100% fine to me - perfectly idiomatic!

Comment: Is there a typo? I think you meant for the idiomatic version to use "the time" instead of "your time".

Comment: @psmears: Oops, my bad :-/. Thank you for persisting in telling me I had made a mistake. Fixed now.

Comment: @MichaelSmith: I am not sure what you mean, using neither "taking your time" nor "taking the time". Do you mean "Thank you for writing this wonderful answer!"?

Comment: One way to retain the original sentence structure without risking misinterpretation of the phrase "taking your time" is to replace it with "spending time", as in "Thank you for spending [your] time writing those letters".

Answer (score 8):

There's nothing really wrong with either one. I just maybe suggest

> Thank you for taking ***the*** time to write this wonderful answer!

I think that that's more commonly used.

Comment: Although this doesn't answer my particular question, thank you for pointing out another mistake I made.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you upvoted too! Stack Exchange discourages using comments to say "thanks".

There is little wrong with either sentence. Both a gerund and a to-infinitive are correct here. I don't detect much difference in nuance.  You could insert an "in" to say "...taking your time in writing", but I don't think it adds much. I prefer "in" over "for" in this sentence.

Given a choice, I prefer the infinitive. It is, perhaps, slightly more straightforward.

Comment: I did upvote, and even marked the answer as accepted :) To your answer, I would only object that in the original sentence, 'writing' is part of a participle phrase, not a gerund. If I had put 'in' or 'for' right before 'writing', it would be a gerund. Nevermind, I'll still upvote and mark your question as accepted, too :)